# Image not moving to the bottom of screen during animation in android

Tags: android

I am new to android.
I am doing a project in which I want to move the image from top to bottom of the screen.
I have written the code for that but my image moves upto middle of the screen and returns to the top of the screen without reaching down to the bottom...

this is my MainActicity.java file

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_eg_main);

    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.testing);
    image.startAnimation(animation);
```

this is my res/layout/activity_eg_main.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   tools:context="com.example.example.EgMainActivity" >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hehe"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

this is my res/anim/testing.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate
             android:fromYDelta="0"
             android:toYDelta="100"
             android:duration="1000">
    </translate>

 </set>
```

please suggest the corrections as soon as possible...
thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 1):

```
<translate
         android:fromYDelta="0%"
         android:toYDelta="100%"
         android:duration="1000">
</translate>
```

else follow this approach

Make a folder anim in the res folder of the project. Now add slide_up.xml for slide_up animation. Then add slide_down.xml for slide down animation.

Code for slide_down.xml:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:fromYDelta="-1000" android:duration="1500"/>
</set>
```

Code for slide_up.xml:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:fromYDelta="1000" android:duration="1500"/>
</set>
```

To start it attach it to object you want to be animated:

```
Animation slideUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_up);
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgv);
img.startAnimation(slideUp);
```

Comment: thank you for your reply.......the slide_up.xml works fine...but not slide_down_xml.
how can I make sure that it works for different screen sizes....

Comment: thank you for your reply.......the slide_up.xml works fine...but not slide_down_xml.
how can I make sure that it works for different screen sizes....
if i use % the animation is not reaching down......I would like to hear a good answer that works for screens of different length and uses % for android:fromXXXX attributes....
please do post the answer as soon as possible...

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, I got it...
changing android:fromYDelta to "0%p" and android:toYDelta to "100%p" did the trick...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
      android:fromYDelta="0%p"
      android:toYDelta="100%p"
      android:duration="5000"
     />

 </set>
```